# Error: initializing source docker://ibmcom/mq:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io .... connection refused

Tags: ibm-mq, podman

I am using Linux and trying to simulate a ibm mq server by myself via podman, however i got issue in podman run. I have added the docker.io to localhost in /etc/hosts. however i still got this issue, does someone know what i am missing here?
Thank you in advance.

Calling podman run to start the server in container [ibm_mqserver] public port is [51672] ...
Trying to pull docker.io/ibmcom/mq:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://ibmcom/mq:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:62268->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

below is the error screenshot
[Podman Run Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTDsS.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of writing the location for the latest MQ image is `icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq:latest`

Comment: hi, I have the same config on another server and it works there, but not on this server, I just dont know what is missing on my current server...